# How to prevent rotation of a gltf model in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, web-ar

I am trying to create a jewelry AR try on using **Jeeliz Facetracking** and **three.js**. Face tracking and model tracking are working totally fine but I don't want my model to rotate based on the head rotation. So how can I prevent the gltf model/scene from rotating?. I appreciate any help, Thanks in advance.
code is attached.

```js
"use strict";

const SETTINGS = {
  gltfModelURL: 'necklace01/necklace01.gltf',
  cubeMapURL: 'Bridge2/',
  offsetYZ: [-0.3, 0], // offset of the model in 3D along vertical and depth axis
  scale: 2
};

let THREECAMERA = null;


// build the 3D. called once when Jeeliz Face Filter is OK
function init_threeScene(spec){
  const threeStuffs = JeelizThreeHelper.init(spec, null);

  // CREATE THE ENVMAP:
  const path = SETTINGS.cubeMapURL;
  const format = '.jpg';
  const envMap = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load( [
    path + 'posx' + format, path + 'negx' + format,
    path + 'posy' + format, path + 'negy' + format,
    path + 'posz' + format, path + 'negz' + format
  ] );

  // IMPORT THE GLTF MODEL:
  // from https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf
  const gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  gltfLoader.load( SETTINGS.gltfModelURL, function ( gltf ) {
    gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {
      if ( child.isMesh ) {
        child.material.envMap = envMap;
        child.material.emissive =  child.material.color;
                child.material.emissiveMap = child.material.map ;
      }
    } );
    gltf.scene.frustumCulled = false;
    
    // center and scale the object:
    const bbox = new THREE.Box3().expandByObject(gltf.scene);

    // center the model:
    const centerBBox = bbox.getCenter(new THREE.Vector3());
    gltf.scene.position.add(centerBBox.multiplyScalar(-1));
    gltf.scene.position.add(new THREE.Vector3(0,SETTINGS.offsetYZ[0], SETTINGS.offsetYZ[1]));


    // scale the model according to its width:
    const sizeX = bbox.getSize(new THREE.Vector3()).x;
    gltf.scene.scale.multiplyScalar(SETTINGS.scale / sizeX);

// dispatch the model:
    threeStuffs.faceObject.add(gltf.scene);
  } ); //end gltfLoader.load callback
  
  //CREATE THE CAMERA
  THREECAMERA = JeelizThreeHelper.create_camera();
} //end init_threeScene()

//entry point, launched by body.onload():
function main(){
  JeelizResizer.size_canvas({
    canvasId: 'jeeFaceFilterCanvas',
    isFullScreen: true,
    callback: start,
    onResize: function(){
      JeelizThreeHelper.update_camera(THREECAMERA);
    }
  })
}

function start(){
  JEELIZFACEFILTER.init({ 
    videoSettings:{ // increase the default video resolution since we are in full screen
      'idealWidth': 1280,  // ideal video width in pixels
      'idealHeight': 800,  // ideal video height in pixels
      'maxWidth': 1920,    // max video width in pixels
      'maxHeight': 1920    // max video height in pixels
    },
    followZRot: true,
    canvasId: 'jeeFaceFilterCanvas',
    NNCPath: '../../../neuralNets/', //root of NN_DEFAULT.json file
    callbackReady: function(errCode, spec){
      if (errCode){
        console.log('AN ERROR HAPPENS. SORRY BRO :( . ERR =', errCode);
        return;
      }

      console.log('INFO: JEELIZFACEFILTER IS READY');
      init_threeScene(spec);
    }, //end callbackReady()

    // called at each render iteration (drawing loop):
    callbackTrack: function(detectState){
      JeelizThreeHelper.render(detectState, THREECAMERA);
    }
  }); //end JEELIZFACEFILTER.init call
} //end start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent rotation implementing the line bellow in your code. remeber to import:
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

**orbitControls.autoRotate = false;**